# How can I start postgres automatically on startup?

Tags: bash, startup, login, postgresql

I can start postgres with:

```
# Start Postgres
/usr/local/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l logfile start
```

Where can I put that to start up when I start the machine up?

I can put it in my `.bash_login` file but then I get a new instance of postgres each time I do a new window which is not good.

I only want it to happen when I initially log in to the machine.

This is for OS-X Lion, Macbook Air bought Nov 2011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for Apple systems you should add a .plist to your [Launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) configuration.

Exactly how to do this varies a little from Mac OS X release to Mac OS X release. You haven't specified yours so I can't give a more specific answer.

The main thing to be aware of is that your postgresql plist should make sure to run PostgreSQL as the correct user.

If you use the [EnterpriseDB installers for PostgreSQL](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#osx) they should take care of this task for you.

Comment: launchd is definitely the recommended way to go. I like Lingon (http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/index.html) for setting up the tasks. Easier than messing with plist files.